# Invoke hook from React Router data router action

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

I am using React Router 6.4.3 with the new data routers.

A 3rd party authentication library exposes an authentication context and a login function through a hook, like:

```tsx
const { AuthenticationContext, login } = useAuthentication();
```

I already managed to wrap the routes into the `AuthenticationContext` by using a pathless route in `createBrowserRouter`.

However, I fail to understand how I could make use of route actions to perform the login and redirect the user afterwards. As configuration and action are now outside of a functional component, I cannot make use of the `useAuthentication` hook.

My configuration looks like this:

```tsx
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from 'auth';
import Login, { action as loginAction } from './routes/login';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <AuthProvider />,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/login',
                element: <Login />,
                action: loginAction,
            },
        ],
    },
]);

function App() {
    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    );
}
```

With `loginAction` currently only a stub:

```tsx
const action = async ({ request, params }) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    // How to invoke login() method exposed by useAuthentication() hook here?

}
```

The `AuthenticationContext` and associated methods roughly look like this:

```tsx
const loginApi = async (email, password) => {
   // ajax call to login endpoint
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

const AuthProvider = () => {
    const [jwt, setJwt] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const login = async (email, password) => {
        const jwt = await loginApi(email, password);
        setJwt(jwt);
        navigate('/dashboard');
    }

    const contextValue = {
        jwt,
        login: handleLogin,
    }
 
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            <Outlet />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default AuthProvider;
export { useAuth };
```

Is there a way to make this work with the data routers without touching the auth lib?

Comment: Is `AuthProvider` providing the Context value for the `useAuthentication ` hook? Can you share the `AuthProvider` component code? You likely need to refactor the code a bit to have the `login` component in scope when creating the browser router.

Comment: @DrewReese I have enhanced my question with an excerpt of the authentication methods. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You very likely need to refactor the code a bit to allow the `App` component to use the `useAuthentication` hook so it can access the `login` function so it can be passed to the `loginAction` handler.

Example:

'./routes/login'

```tsx
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const action = ({ login }) => async ({ request, params }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);

  // call login, and redirect upon success
  await login(...);
  ...
  redirect('/dashboard');
};
```

App

```tsx
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login, { action as loginAction } from './routes/login';

function App() {
  const { login } = useAuthentication();

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    ....,
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: <Login />,
      action: loginAction({ login }),
    },
    ....
  ]);

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

index.js

```tsx
import { AuthProvider } from 'auth';

...

<AuthProvider>
  </App />
</AuthProvider>
```

AuthenticationContext

```tsx
const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [jwt, setJwt] = useState(null);

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    const jwt = await loginApi(email, password);
    setJwt(jwt);
    // return success/fail for login action handler
  }

  const contextValue = {
    jwt,
    login: handleLogin,
  }
 
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds helpful. Currently the AuthProvider's login method attempts to redirect on its own after successful login, therefore putting the AuthProvider around the router won't work. I'll try and get rid of that part and report back.

Comment: @digitalbreed Yeah, you posted the implementation right before I initially posted answer and I saw that you were rendering the `AuthProvider` *inside* the router so it could use the navigate function. You can split the logic a bit and redirect to the dashboard from within the `loginAction` function using the [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility. I tweaked my answer a bit just now to adjust.

Comment: Took me a minute to notice that I had to replace the `<Outlet/>` with the regular React `children` prop again, but once I had that taken care of everything worked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Adding another idea to the mix. When you return in an action, the returned data becomes available in your component via the `useActionData` hook. My simplified registration component, for example, looks like:

```
import { Navigate, useActionData } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "context/auth";

export default function Register() {
  const { user, error } = useActionData();
  const { login } = useAuth();

  if (user) {
    const { token, refreshToken, ...rest } = user;
    login(token, refreshToken, rest);
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
  }

  return <RegistrationForm error={error} />
}
```

My register route's action:

```
async function action ({ request }) {
  const body = await request.json();
  try {
    // depending on your API you might await then return
    return fetch(apiUrls.PUBLIC_AUTH_URL, {
      headers,
      method,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return { error, user: null };
  }
}
```