# Passing a function to a react-router action in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-router, auth0

I am trying to use Auth0's `useAuth0()` hook to retrieve `getAccessTokenSilently()` in a react-router action, so I can get an access token to make a protected API call to my service to execute the action.

Based on [this past similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296504/invoke-hook-from-react-router-data-router-action) it appears the way to do this is to call the hook in the parent App component then pass it as a function to any loaders or actions that need it. Cool, sounds great!

Unfortunately TypeScript flat out refuses to allow this.

I've tried creating a custom type that extends ActionFunctionArgs so TypeScript knows there will be another property, but that just results in errors about how my action function can't be assigned to the action: property of the route.

Has anyone ever done this successfully? How do you use an authentication hook inside an action in TypeScript? Is there another way this should be done?

Edit: here's code.

main.tsx:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

appAction.mts (the action I want to use authentication stuff in):

```js
import { ActionFunction } from "react-router-dom";

export const appAction: ActionFunction =
  ({ getAccessTokenSilently }) =>
  async ({ request, params }) => {
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const intent = formData.get("intent");

    // Do something with the token here when calling an API.
  };
```

App.tsx:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      element: <Auth0ProviderLayout />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [    
        {
          path: "/verifier",
          element: <ProtectedRoute component={Verifier} />,
          loader: activeFlightPlansLoader,
          action: appAction({ getAccessTokenSilently }),
... etc
```

Typescript has many issues with this.

- For the `appAction` function definition it says:

> "Property 'getAccessTokenSilently' does not exist on type 'ActionFunctionArgs'"

- For the assignment of `appAction` to the `action` property when creating the routes it says:

> Type 'DataFunctionValue | Promise' is not
> assignable to type 'ActionFunction | undefined'. Type 'null' is not
> assignable to type 'ActionFunction | undefined'

and:

> Argument of type '{ getAccessTokenSilently: { (options:
> GetTokenSilentlyOptions & { detailedResponse: true; }):
> Promise; (options?:
> GetTokenSilentlyOptions | undefined): Promise<...>; (options:
> GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Promise<...>; }; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'ActionFunctionArgs'.   Object literal may only
> specify known properties, and 'getAccessTokenSilently' does not exist
> in type 'ActionFunctionArgs'.

Comment: AFAIK the curried action function *should* work just fine in Typescript. Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `appAction` is not of type `ActionFunction`, but is a function that ***returns*** an action function of that type.

```js
import type { ActionFunction } from "react-router-dom";

interface AppAction {
  getAccessTokenSilently: () => Promise<string>; // <-- or whatever this needs to be
}

const appAction = ({
  getAccessTokenSilently
}: AppAction): ActionFunction => async ({ request, params }) => {
  const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const intent = formData.get("intent");

  // Do something with the token here when calling an API.
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a ton and it does get passed through properly, unlocking a major understanding for me of how to use actions (and loaders).

Now I just have to figure out why it thinks it wasn't called from inside an <Auth0Provider> (which is what the top-level element is for, from this StackOverflow q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73934043/how-to-use-auth0-provider-with-the-new-createbrowsererouter-in-v6-4.

Comment: It is working fine for everything outside of the action (yay? yay!). I was able to get all of my login/signout/register/protected routes working based on that other post (why Auth0 doesn't show how to do that in their docs mystifies me).

Comment: @NeilE Dunno. ‍♂️ I've never used auth0 so have next to nothing of any experience with it. I think they need to catch up to `react-router-dom@6` though since RRDv6 has been out well over a year now.

Comment: I think everything needs to catch up with react-router-dom@6  At least it feels that way sometimes!